Is there a way to search/sort an AZURE Storage Container
I have an Azure storage container with multiple .csv files Prefixed with a vendor name, the file name, and the Date example Vendor_RecordResult_OCT_01:01:01 AM. Is there a way to Search/Sort the Container contents?

Just found Microsoft Azure storage explorer
